# How do I detect the RAM memory chip specification from within a Linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I'd like to add more RAM to my Ubuntu installation ( running on a Dell Inspiron 640m ). Is there any inbuilt command or package to find out the current RAM chip specifications (manufacturer, type, speed etc) from within Linux ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help: [**Linux: Check Ram Speed and Type**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-ram-speed-linux/).

> sudo dmidecode --type 17

Alternatively, if you can boot from a windows system, the [Crucial System Scanner tool](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) will give very good details on what is installed and what can be upgraded on the system (along with a shopping cart too). It will need an Internet connection.

Here is a quick reference from Crucial:
[**Guaranteed-compatible memory upgrades for your Dell Inspiron 640m Laptop/Notebook**](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/compatible-memory-for/Dell/Inspiron+640m/list.html)

I am assuming, you do not want to open the system and look at the memory sticks.
That is [quick and simple too](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins640m/en/SM/memory.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, since your machine is from a major manufacturer, you can use an online tool such as [Kingston's memory search](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory) to lookup the memory type from the model number.

[Search Results for: Dell Inspiron 640m](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/discontinuedmodels?model=29917&devicetype=3&mfr=DEL&line=Inspiron)