# How can I determine the fastest RAM I can put in my laptop ?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, ddr

I would like to add some RAM to my laptop but I have one small problem: I would like to know what is the fastest speed I can put inside it.

I know from CPU-Z that I use DDR3 RAM:

One piece of RAM is PC3-10700 (667 Mhz) and the other is  PC3-8500F (533 Mhz)

I use Acer Travel Mate 5742G if that's relevant. My Chipset is Intel Havendale/Clarkdale Host Bridge.

Comment: See: [Rules for adding/upgrading RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/20186/rules-for-adding-upgrading-ram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You laptop will take up to 8GB and the fastest speed it will take is DDR3 PC3-10600 . 
You can buy it here >> http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=E5A23A8EA5CA7304

Comment: By googling the model number of your laptop along with the word ram, this will then bring up hundreds of websites listing the spec of ram the computer takes, the fastest, max allowed, pin number etc etc. All the info is on the left hand side of the link above. Memory:
DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 PC3-8500
Memory Type: DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 PC3-8500, DDR3 (non-ECC)
Maximum Memory: 8GB 
Slots: 2
Each memory slot can hold DDR3 PC3-10600, DDR3 PC3-8500 with a maximum of 4GB per slot

Answer (score 1):

You can put a faster ram, it will just run at a slower speed. I’ve had once some 133MHz SDR sticks running at 100MHz.

Comment: True, even with the very latest memory. But one should always check the "compatibility" informations. It happens that one stick will run, and the other won't.